# Table does not exist when create a stored procedure in Oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle

I create a database with the name Test. There is a table named Banks , that exists and also have data. I generate this table by using EF core in asp.net core api project.

When I try to create a stored procedure GetAllEntities , I get an error

Table or View does not exist

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE GetAllEntities (
    p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_cursor FOR
    SELECT * FROM Banks;
END GetAllEntities;
```

Can anyone help to find out the solution for it?

Comment: If the system tells you that banks doesn't exist, it is literally so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is about letter case. Oracle is case-insensitive, **unless** you created table (or any other object) by enclosing its name into double quotes.

For example:

```
SQL> create table "Banks" (id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into "Banks" values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from "Banks";

        ID
----------
         1
```

Now see this: I followed letter case (capital "B", lower "anks"), but - without double quotes - that table doesn't exist:

```
SQL> select * From Banks;
select * From Banks
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL>
```

Therefore, that might be the case in your procedure as well. I noticed you used `Banks`, but without double quotes. If you add them:

```
SQL> create or replace PROCEDURE GetAllEntities (
  2      p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  3  )
  4  AS
  5  BEGIN
  6      OPEN p_cursor FOR
  7      SELECT * FROM "Banks";       --> here
  8  END GetAllEntities;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

---

This might, or might not be reason for error you got. If what I wrote doesn't help, please, post some more info - especially, prove that table whose name is `Banks` exists in schema in which you're creating that procedure.

Comment: Yes, it was required to add "" for Banks, 
"Banks"
Now it works , thanks.